# Delete an element from an ordered set of records Ada

Tags: containers, ada

I have constructed an ordered set of records in Ada.

```ada
with Ada.Containers.Ordered_Sets;

procedure Demonstrator is

   type Streams is (Mech);
   type Gend is (Female, Male);

   type Student_Details is record
      Roll_Number    : Positive range 1 .. 100;
      Name           : String (1 .. 5);
      Age            : Natural range 18 .. 40;
      DOB            : String (1 .. 8);
      Department     : Streams;
      Admission_Date : String (1 .. 8);
      Pursuing_Year  : Integer range 2010 .. 2099;
      Gender         : Gend;
   end record;

   function "<" (Left, Right : Student_Details) return Boolean is
   begin
      return Left.Roll_Number < Right.Roll_Number;
   end "<";

   package Student_Sets is
     new Ada.Containers.Ordered_Sets (Element_Type => Student_Details);
   use Student_Sets;

   Student_Store : Student_Sets.Set;
begin
   Student_Store.Insert ((2, "iuytr", 19, "28031989", MECH, "26072018", 2018, Male));
   Student_Store.Insert ((4, "cobol", 19, "28031989", MECH, "26072018", 2018, Male));
   Student_Store.Insert ((3, "sdfsd", 19, "28031989", MECH, "26072018", 2018, Male));
   Student_Store.Insert ((5, "sfdff", 19, "28031989", MECH, "26072018", 2018, Male));
end Demonstrator;
```

Now I want to access an element who has the Roll number 5 and delete it.

```
    Student_Store.Delete(Student_Details.Roll_Number => 5)
```

is not able to delete it.
Can you please help to delete a member by referencing it with a particular key.

Also on a separate note how to define the key to sort an ordered set while intialization in case of a record being an element.

Comment: I don't have the time right now to give a complete answer, but you should look into `Generic_Keys`, which is a generic inner package within `Ada.Containers.Ordered_Sets`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure your data structure should be a set?  The way you want to treat it, I get the impression that it rather should be a map with `Roll_Number` as the key.

If it really should be a set, then @egilhh's comment points us in the right direction:

```ada
with Ada.Containers.Ordered_Sets;

procedure Demonstrator is

   type Streams is (Mech);
   type Gend is (Male);

   type Student_Details is record
      Roll_Number    : Positive range 1 .. 100;
      Name           : String (1 .. 5);
      Age            : Natural range 18 .. 40;
      DOB            : String (1 .. 8);
      Department     : Streams;
      Admission_Date : String (1 .. 8);
      Pursuing_Year  : Integer range 2010 .. 2099;
      Gender         : Gend;
   end record;

   function "<" (Left, Right : Student_Details) return Boolean is
   begin
      return Left.Roll_Number < Right.Roll_Number;
   end "<";

   function Roll_Number (Item : in Student_Details) return Positive is
     (Item.Roll_Number);

   package Student_Sets is
     new Ada.Containers.Ordered_Sets (Element_Type => Student_Details);

   package Roll_Numbers is
     new Student_Sets.Generic_Keys (Key_Type => Positive,
                                    Key      => Roll_Number);

   use all type Student_Sets.Set;

   Student_Store : Student_Sets.Set;
begin
   Student_Store.Insert ((2, "iuytr", 19, "28031989", MECH, "26072018", 2018, Male));
   Student_Store.Insert ((4, "cobol", 19, "28031989", MECH, "26072018", 2018, Male));
   Student_Store.Insert ((3, "sdfsd", 19, "28031989", MECH, "26072018", 2018, Male));
   Student_Store.Insert ((5, "sfdff", 19, "28031989", MECH, "26072018", 2018, Male));

   Roll_Numbers.Delete (Container => Student_Store,
                        Key       => 5);
end Demonstrator;
```

Comment: I am not sure about a map on the regard of avoiding duplicate elements. I was looking at hashed sets if they could do the trick but i am not sure. What has to be done is that data set should be searchable through a unique non repeatable roll number. And by the way i am just 20 days old to ada so a lot of syntactic errors are there. I was in c programming but something came up.

Comment: Your implementation guarantees that you don't have duplicate elements, but it doesn't ensure that the roll-number is unique.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully you will see a lo of ada question posted by me in the coming days. :) Thanks and Cheers!